# When referring to an older version of macOS, do we still call it OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, ipados

I'm currently writing up some documentation for a project that has two implementations of the same feature: One uses Cocoa (10.10+) for compatibility and the other, SwiftUI (10.15+).

When referring to the Cocoa build, should one use the *"deprecated"* name? ie.

- OS X 10.10 and higher
- macOS 10.10 and higher

---

**Bonus question:** When referring to a project that is universally compatible with both iOS and iPadOS (all of my UIKit projects, essentially), is it proper to simply refer to it as an "iOS project?" Or would it be more accurate to include both variations of the OS name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's docs are using macOS even for builds before the rename.
Using [NSStackView's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstackview), you can see they're using "macOS 10.9+".

In practice, people won't be confused if you use them interchangeably though.

---

Update for the bonus question:
Apple's docs provide answers here, too!
Looking at SwiftUI's [List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list), you can see that they don't call out iPadOS specifically, and just lump it in with iOS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple Style Guide](https://help.apple.com/applestyleguide/#/apsg1eef9171), you should use "OS X Yosemite 10.10 or later" (except in developer documentation, which uses "macOS" when the range includes 10.12 or later versions). Here's [the relevant section](https://help.apple.com/applestyleguide/#/apsg72b28652?sub=apd246e83209):

> Mac operating systems have a version name and a version number. If you
> include both the name and the number, place the name first. Don’t
> place the name in quotation marks, and don’t include the word
> *version* or the letter *v*.
>
> To refer to specific versions of the Mac operating system, follow
> these guidelines, depending on the version number:
>
> - *10.12 or later*: Use *macOS*. To refer to a specific version of macOS, you can use its name, its version number, or both. Always include
>   *macOS*.
>
>   macOS Sierra
>       macOS 10.12
>       macOS Sierra 10.12
> - *10.8 through 10.11*: Use *OS X*. To refer to a specific version of OS X, you can use its name, its version number, or both. Always include *OS
>   X*.
>
>   OS X El Capitan
>       OS X 10.11
>       OS X El Capitan 10.11
> - *10.0 through 10.7*: Use *Mac OS X*. Include the version number only.
>
>   *Correct*: Mac OS X 10.7
>
>   *Incorrect*: Mac OS X Lion 10.7
>
> When referring to a range of OS versions that includes both macOS and
> earlier versions, use the name (or version number) of the earliest
> version followed by *or later*.
>
> *Correct*: To use Handoff, you must have OS X Yosemite 10.10 or later
> installed.
>
> *Incorrect*: To use Handoff, you must have macOS Yosemite 10.10 or later
> installed. [Version 10.10 was called *OS X*, not *macOS*.]
>
> *Exception*: If a range of versions includes both macOS and earlier
> versions, developer publications refer to all included versions as
> *macOS*.